# "On the lateral surface, there are...": Do I need to use a comma after "surface"?

Tags: commas

"On the lateral surface, there are small insertions of brown siderite."

Is there any general rule for punctuating sentences like this? Can you give me a source reference?

Answer (score 0):

[The link here](https://www.businessinsider.in/THE-COMMA-SUTRA-13-Rules-For-Using-Commas-Without-Looking-Like-An-Idiot/articleshow/22667230.cms) should explain when to use commas. But the answer to your question : yes should use (,) there to depict a pause as a narrative. It might be acceptable without the comma as well but it will be a just a simple statement. To make it more informative you may use the comma.

Also for [comma usage rules - By Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma/) , refer this link.

Comment: Hello, K. Your first linked article doesn't address this situation. Grammarly has 'When an adverbial phrase begins a sentence, it’s often followed by a comma but it doesn’t have to be, especially if it’s short....' It would be better to add this to an answer. However, this has been covered on ELU before.

Comment: Hi, Edwin, thanks for the heads up. I answered not just considering the question but also the 'comma-dilemma'. You are definitely right, if it's short we should not put the comma to force-punctuate it. I saw it as a narrative, like they do in Discovery or Nat-Geo; they pause for a second during these situations. My response was with regard to that. I appreciate you pointed out, thanks. Cheers!